# Server Side Webpage Screenshots - Windows Server

Tags: screenshot, capture, printscreen

ive written a script that configures a bunch of items and displays it on screen using javascript. Now we are in the process of trying to take a screenshot of it via a browser. This particular webpage is for use by the general public, and once the screenshot is taken, we post the photo to facebook for the user.

Ive trialled a number of services that take screenshots but they are all pretty slow, mostly averaging around 25 - 25 seconds to take the shot and have it saved on the server. All our users would leave in this time =(

Ive also tried the application from http://www.websitescreenshots.com/ and whilst its brilliant i cant get it to render our page with the js on it.

I have found this to be a common thing amongst screenshot software, and ive even gone through to trying to take advantage of the free webservice from Wordpress MShots.

Whilst it took photos nicely you could never tell how long it was going to take and not good enough for a production website.

So can anyone recommend a utility that will allow screenshots of URL's accessible via a command line that can render JS and also runs on windows server 2008 ? I am having no luck tryning to source an app that does this..

Comment: Why do you need to take a screenshot? Why can't you compose the items in a `System.Drawing` graphics context and render a bitmap on the server?

Comment: I wouldnt have a clue on how to do that and also the content is rendered inside a browser as a webpage with parameters defined in the URL and rendered via JS. and then we brand the image with the users session data.